# function ssh2_connect doesnot exist

Tags: php, ssh

I'm trying to set a ssh call to a button using PHP.

When I tried the ssh using `ssh2_connect()` function , the following **error** occurred in my browser :

> function ssh2_connect does not exist

**Packages installed :**

```
automake make php-devel libtool openssl-devel gcc++ gcc

wget http://pecl.php.net/get/ssh2-0.12.tgz
```

**After installation** **I could not find the `ssh2.ini` file**. I have only the `ssh2.so` file in my extensions directory.

**Request :**

Please help me resolve this problem, so that I can successfully `ssh` to my target server .

**My Code :**

1. **example.php** (setting a ssh action to a button , this redirects to index.php )

   ```
   <form action="index.php"method="get">
       <input type="hidden" name="act" value="run">
       <input type="submit" value="run">
   </form>
   ```
2. **index.php**

   ```
   <?php

       if (!function_exists("ssh2_connect")) die("function ssh2_connect doesnot exist");

        if (!($con = ssh2_connect("My server IP", 22))){
             echo "fail:unable to establish connection";
        }else{
             echo "we are logged in ";
        if (!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "ls -al"))) {
             echo "fail:unable to exec command";
        }else{
             stream_set_blocking($stream,true);
             $data = "";
             while ($buf = fread($stream,4096)){
             $data .= $buf;
        }
        fclose($stream);
       }
   }
   ?>
   ```

Comment: using  `phpinfo()` check ssh2 is available or not. If not add `extension=ssh2.so` in php.ini and restart apache or ngix whichever web server you're using

Comment: Hi haridharshan ,
I tried this .phpinfo() is fine . now i am getting a different error with ssh2 . Unable to establish connection . Please help me in resolving this error.

Comment: yes?? Does that worked?

Comment: phpinfo() worked. But when running ssh2_connect() function , it is throwing " unable to establish connection " error .

Comment: You can try the example provided here [ssh2_connect PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php) with debug method to identify the problem of **unable to establish connection**. One reason could be that the **ssh server on port 22** is not accepting the incoming  request.

Comment: Thank you Haridharshan . The manual was really helpfull .